# Code completion for CSS declaration properties

Tags: webstorm

In WebStorm if I type:

```
.foo {
  text-tr
```

the IDE does not offer to autocomplete the property to `text-transform`. I have to type the whole property name.

If it type:

```
.foo {
  text-transform: cap
```

then I do get an offer to complete the value to `capitalize`.

How can I get WebStorm to offer autocomplete suggestions for the property too?

Version: 2021.1

[image]

Comment: 1) What file is that? Plain CSS? Sass/Less/etc? 2) Is that standalone/separate file or a block inside the HTML file? 3) Any template languages are used (e.g. is this some `file.css.liquid` or alike). 4) Have you tried having closing `}` in place? ANYWAY: Give a context/full IDE screenshots etc (details matter) .. because it works fine in a plain .css file -- https://i.imgur.com/pdta1ij.png (PhpStorm 2021.1.2 but that's the same as WebStorm in this regard). **P.S.** Could be one of the custom plugins -- try disabling all custom plugins and restart IDE. Any difference?

Comment: works fine for me; do you have any third-party plugins installed? **NativeScript**, for example? it's known for breaking CSS code completion

Comment: 1) It is a scss file 2) Standalone file 3) No template languages 4) I have tried with a closing '}' 5) I did New > Stylesheet > CSS file 6) No diiference on restart - I added a screenshot above

Comment: UPDATE, it is working but sometimes it takes 10 seconds for the suggestions to appear. Anything I can do about that?

Comment: @dbj44 *"it is working but sometimes it takes 10 seconds for the suggestions to appear"* In such case I personally would suggest to use `Help | Contact Support...` in WebStorm and provide any details there: at very least your `idea.log` file (`Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data`) to start with. **P.S.** Will it work in a brand new project? It works just fine for me on my setup (same code as on your screenshot). Could be specific to your set up/environment. The JB support will look at that if you provide them the files they request.

Comment: On a brand new project, it works very fast.

Comment: @dbj44 If it's fast in a new project .. then you definitely need to contact JB Support: Maybe you can share the project with them / list of modules you are using etc (at least your scss files) so they try it locally. Sadly there wont be a universal solution here if it works fine in one project and not so well in another.